# Find the characteristic polynomial of a $10\times 10$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, characteristic-polynomial

Let  $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & ... & &  &  &  &  &  ...& 0\\ 
0 &0  &1  &. .. &  &  &  &  &  ...&0 \\ 
 0& 0 &0  &1  &...  &  &  &  &  ...&0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &0  &1  & ... &  &  &  ...&0 \\ 
 .&  &...  &  &  &  &  &  & ... & \\ 
 .&  & ... &  &  &  &\ddots  &  & ... & \\ 
 .&  &...  &  &  &  & &  & ... &\\ 
 .&  &...  &  &  &  &  &  & ... & \\ 
 0&0  &0  &...  &  &  &  &  &  ...& 1\\ 
 10^{10}& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0  &  0& 0 &0  &0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Find the characteristic polynomial. This probably needs a trick I don't know. Does someone know it and want to share it with me?

Comment: Have you learned about [companion matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)?

Comment: No but how could I use that ? it's like the "opposite" of the matrix A.

Comment: This doesn't need a trick.  Just write down $A-\lambda I$ and expand by minors along the first column.

Comment: @PetrosK By "opposite" do you perhaps mean... "transpose"?

Comment: Hint: determinant is unaffected by transposes.

Comment: If $N$ as in an $N \times N$ matrix is less than a million I just put this into software. Sometimes even if $N$ is more than a million. Not to devalue other approaches, only to suggest that this approach is often available.

Comment: I'd suggest experimenting with something similar but easier, like $\pmatrix{0&1&0\cr0&0&1\cr a&0&0\cr}$, maybe the $4\times4$ if you need to, seeing the pattern, and then generalizing.

Comment: is the answer $-10^{10}$ ??

Comment: Char poly is $\lambda ^{10}-10^{10}$

Comment: I don't know how to solve it maybe it has to do something with zero blocks etc which I don't  understand complete

Answer (score 0):

I will go with 3x3 example cause it's just easier to write it.

I thought it would be a good idea to take the $(A)^t$ but then I am stuck again because i don't know how to calculate the $det(A)^t-tI_{10})$

$(A)^t-tI_3=\begin{pmatrix}
-t& 0 & a\\ 
 1&  -t&0 \\ 
 0& 1 & -t 
\end{pmatrix}$ so if this was a $10x10$ matrix how should I calculate the determinant ?

Comment: Perhaps your question is simply about how to find the determinant of a sparse matrix that is larger than $3\times 3$.  Are you familiar with Laplace expansion or expansion by minors?